# QFileDialog is crashing my application

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

QFileDialog in the following simple code is crashing my application. It worked the first 3 times I lunched my application and then without even change the function in which QFileDialog is used it is crashing on run-time.

```
void Browse::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
    QString direc=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Directory"),"/home",0,0,QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
    ui->lineEdit->setText(direc);
}
```

I used the

```
QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog;
```

as suggested by [this webpage](http://sarbojitqtexp.blogspot.com/2012/04/getting-crash-on-qfiledialog-static.html)  by still it crashes.

Any idea why? I am aiming to have the user browse the system to select a file or folder. If you have another work to perform this task let me know.

Using ubuntu and Qt.

Comment: crashing how ? seg fault ? what's the error message be more explicit

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33119

Answer (score 1):

Check the page you linked to again: you need to pass QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog into the getOpenFileName call, not just as its own statement.